# No Exception Handling in GDAL/OGR java bindings: ogr.UseExceptions() has no effect

Tags: gdal, java, ogr

When a GDAL/OGR 2.0.1 swig/java operation encounters an error, the message is written to stderr but no exception is thrown within the application -allowing it to continue, which is highly undesirable.I have tried `ogr.UseExceptions()` but this seems to just erase the error message from stderr and not result in a thrown exception within the application!

Is there another method required to get the error handling to work properly, or is this just a limitation with the bindings?

Comment: What version of GDAL/OGR bindings are you using? I'm asking because `UseExceptions()` states it is available "Since: Java bindings 1.7.0"

Comment: I'm using 2.0.1

Comment: Was this ever resolved for you? Having the same issue.